# How to Edit xml child node with php

Tags: php, xml

i already search here before i ask this question.. I know there is an answer here somewhere.. but i can't find it..

I want to be able to edit child node by id in my xml file.. i tried alot of script but i'm having a really bad time with this..

please see this line in edit.php:

```
echo "the problem is in the next line";
```

this is the last line that the server reads..

thanks you for your help.

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<events>
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
        <event>a</event>
        <eventDate>a</eventDate>
        <desc>a</desc>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>2</id>
        <event>b</event>
        <eventDate>b</eventDate>
        <desc>b</desc>
    </record>
</events>
```

**edit.php**

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$id = $record["id"];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('events.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = sprintf('/events/record[./id = "%d"]', $id);

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $record) {

    $eventN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("event");
    echo "the problem is in the next line";
    $eventN->item(0)->nodeValue = $record["event"];

    $dateN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("eventDate");
    $dateN->item(0)->nodeValue = $record["eventDate"];

    $descN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("desc");
    $descN->item(0)->nodeValue = $record["desc"];

}
$dom->save("events.xml");
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
?>
```

**Edited: Working edit.php but not dynamic**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$record = array(
    'id' => $_POST['id'],
    'event' => $_POST['event'],
    'eventDate' => $_POST['eventDate'],
    'desc' => $_POST['desc'],
);

$id = $record["id"];
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('events.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = sprintf('/events/record[./id = "%d"]', $id);

foreach($xpath->query($query) as $record) {

    $eventN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("event");
    echo "i change it to string text and it's works. ";
    $eventN->item(0)->nodeValue = 'text';

    $dateN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("eventDate");
    $dateN->item(0)->nodeValue = 'text';

    $descN = $record->parentNode->getElementsByTagName("desc");
    $descN->item(0)->nodeValue = 'text';

}
$dom->save("events.xml");
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
?>
```

Comment: you say that it's the last line the server reads. does it give any errors?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMElement as array in /~/www/ofear.onlinewebshop.net/asce/edit.php on line 24

Comment: the edit.php supposed to get data from a POST data and to search for a specific id and change it's child nodes...

Comment: well..the problem is that the $record["event"] can't work.. but if i doing this for example '$record["event"]' <- like a string , then it's works and edit the childes

Comment: how can i make the $record["event"] to be a string?

Comment: Please see the first post in the topic. i edit it, and it's shown a working script, but not what i wanted..

Comment: Please look in this link: http://codepad.org/dakCUgCf

Comment: i need to change the array to a string.. how can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the issue is your `$record` array from the beginning is overwritten in the `foreach`.

[image]

Either change the as `$record` or change the name of the array holding the `$_POST` data.

On a sidenote, you are iterating over  elements, so there is no reason to get to the parentNode. Use

```
$record->getElementsByTagName("event");
```